# Can SP2T RF switches be considered failsafe?

Tags: rf, switches, solid-state-relay, solid-state-devices, fail-safe

I am looking for a RF switch that is failsafe.

For failsafe I mean:

- a device that defaults to a useful state during total power loss (no supply voltage, no control voltage)
- for a RF switch, a device that defaults to a high isolation path during total power loss

Sometimes, manufacturer specify whether a device is failsafe or not ([this is a good example](https://www.guerrilla-rf.com/products/DataSheet?sku=6011&file_name=GRF6011DS.pdf)); but most of the times they do not.

So, my question is: is it correct to assume that, when it is not powered, a RF switch is in its default state

Comment: Anything that isn't powered is in a default state.

Comment: That's not entirely true.  Latching relays stay in the their last state (open or closed) with power removed.